# How to get string for a DomElement?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a `DomElement` which unfortunately does not have the `saveXML()` method that `DomDocument` has.

I am trying to get the raw XML string representation of the of the DomElement.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `DomElement` has a property of its `DomDocument`, i.e. `ownerDocument`.

Hence you can fetch the XML of the `DomElement` via:

```
$domElementXml = $domElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($domElement);
```

You have to pass the node again as the `ownerDocument` refers to the whole document. So running `$domElement->ownerDocument->saveXML()` would fetch the entire XML of the document which could contain different `DomElement` objects as well.

Comment: You sure figured that out in a hurry!

Comment: @miken32 actually, I didn't

Answer (score 3):

This expands on [k0pernikus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34296402/457268) and includes a SimpleXMLElement variation. It works for any random DOM element without dumping the document XML:

```php
<?php

$outerXmlAsString = $yourDomElementGoesHere
    ->ownerDocument
    ->saveXML($yourDomElementGoesHere);

// or

$outerXmlAsString = simplexml_import_dom($yourDomElementGoesHere)
    ->asXML();
```

Example:

```php
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$root = new DOMElement('root');
$doc->appendChild($root);
$child = new DOMElement('child');
$root->appendChild($child);
$leaf = new DOMElement('leaf','text');
$child->appendChild($leaf);

echo $child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child), PHP_EOL;
echo simplexml_import_dom($child)->asXML(), PHP_EOL;
```

Example output:

```xml
<child><leaf>text</leaf></child>
<child><leaf>text</leaf></child>
```

Test it out on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/W4Fg6).